# Did the Romans use any swear words?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, roman-culture, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

I was reading the book *Lingua Latina, Per Se Illustrata* by Hans H. Ørberg, and I often saw scenes in which persons were angry. In the book, the writer doesn't use any swear words or anything to that effect. Did the ancient Romans use any swear words and, if so, could anyone give an example of a Latin swear word?

Comment: Latin translations have frequently been "bowdlerized" to remove "bad language", sometimes to the great detriment of accuracy.

Comment: This is a vague memory from years ago, I had a good friend who was a pro at Latin and had me read a book written by an aristocrat of the time, language of which was Super vulgar - pretty much 50 shades of grey multiplied by Nero. You'll really have to dig into the subject.

Comment: @seems I'm guessing this is either Petronius's Satyricon or Apuleius's Metamorphoses.

Comment: @seems Maybe you could give some more information? Like sources, (if possible) more memories, etc.

Comment: @seems That sounds like the Satyricon, but there's also the Priapeia which is the most "vulgar" Latin I know of (in the sense of obscene, not the dialect which became Romance).

Comment: @seems: If you remember anything more, please edit your answer. It can be undeleted. Others: If you think that Satyricon, Metamorphoses, or Priapeia would be good examples of vulgar language, please post them as answers! Each one is worth a mention in an answer.

Comment: Oh, good old Internet. One previously normal user suddenly becomes famous when they ask about swearing Romans. The world is so mature. Still, it's an interesting question and was destined to be asked.

Comment: Martial's "Epigrams" are also worth a look for the more 'agricultural' language but worth reading more for their biting wit and scathing attacks but he does have a wonderful turn of phrase. 
A Roman Oscar Wilde... or maybe Oscar was a Victorian Martial.

Comment: I remember the edition of Catullus I used while at school (this side of the millennium) which glossed the dirty Latin into more Latin (*irrumare = mentulam in os inserere* and so on). I think this was fairly common until quite recently.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, they used swear words *all the time*! There's actually a whole book on the subject, [The Latin Sexual Vocabulary](https://books.google.com/books?id=GDP9VHGbF1AC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by J. N. Adams. *Cinaedus* (a pejorative term for a 'bottom'), *mentula* (male genitalia), and *cunnus* (female genitalia) are perhaps the most common and dirtiest insults and are generally
You can see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_profanity) a larger list, too.

There's actually a nice little poem—Catullus 16—containing a quite a few of these swear words, two powerful ones in the first line. Catullus was a Roman living in the first century BCE, and so was a contemporary of Cicero and Caesar. Here are the first four lines:

> Pedicabo ego vos et irrumabo,
> Aureli pathice et cinaede Furi,
> qui me ex versiculis meis putastis,
> quod sunt molliculi, parum pudicum.

This can be vulgarly translated so:

> I will fuck you in the ass and in the mouth
> Cocksucking Aurelius and Butt-boy Furius
> You who think that I, because my verses
> Are a little soft, have no shame.

You can read the whole poem on Rudy Negenborn's site: [Catullus 16](http://rudy.negenborn.net/catullus/text2/e16.htm).

That these words would be considered obscene by the ancients Romans is verified by Martial (3.69) and Cicero (*Fam*. 9.22.3), the latter of whom alludes to *cunnus* and *mentula* as words Romans avoid saying, even to the point that they won't make a diminutive of *menta* (the Latin word for 'mint'):

> Socraten fidibus docuit nobilissimus fidicen; is Connus vocitatus est. num id obscenum putas? ... ‘ruta’ et ‘menta’ recte utrumque. volo mentam pusillam ita appellare ut ‘rutulam’: non licet. belle ‘tectoriola.’ dic ergo etiam ‘pavimenta’ isto modo: non potes. viden igitur nihil esse nisi ineptias, turpitudinem nec in verbo esse nec in re, itaque nusquam esse?

> Socrates was taught the lute by a very celebrated player whose name was Connus. Do you think that obscene? ... Take ‘ruta’ and ‘menta’; both all right. But if I want a word for ‘little mint’ corresponding to ‘rutula,’ I can’t have it.

Cicero goes on and names more, but funny enough, he was actually writing on how ludicrous Roman sensibilities toward obscenities were; even here he doesn't fully say the two words he alludes to.

Comment: The poem also has its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catullus_16).

Comment: "Passer deliciae meae puellae" *(Great translations, btw;)*

Comment: Latin _cunnus_ derived directly into Spanish _coño_ 'cunt', quite a dirty word. Interestingly enough, it also derived into _cunnilingus_, a very polite word today for 'oral sex applied to a woman' even though its dirty origins.

Comment: French con, conne, connard, connasse.