# Are there Latin angry oaths like the English "damn it!" or "for God's sake!"?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, profanity, interjection, slang

Nowadays (I guess) every language has both vulgar and non-vulgar ways to express anger, frustration and/or exasperation , in response to some nuisance. Looking e.g. at Catullus, it seems unlikely that this wasn't the case for Latin.

Do we know any examples of this? Would we hear *Pro Iove!* in the streets of Rome?

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2183/did-the-romans-use-any-swear-words

Comment: There's *edepol*, which more literally means "by Pollux" but is often used in the sense "truly" or "indeed". I guess that wouldn't count as angry, so it doesn't answer your question? This particular word is [widely used](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=edepol).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Yes, I am actually looking for a different kind of interjection, but _edepol_ is interesting. According to Wiktionary, it expresses surprise, annoyance or enthusiasm - not quite what I want, but not so far off, thank you. I see that women specifically, also used _ēcastor_, "by Castor", in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Perii!** seems to be an option.

> par.: quid agis? iocabar equidem.
> chae.: garris.
> par.: **perii!** quid ego egi miser? quo trudis? perculeris iam tu me. tibi equidem dico, mane!

Loeb translation:

> par.: What are you thinking of? I was only joking.
> chae.: Nonsense!
> par.: **Damn it!** Oh, what have I done? (Chaerea pushes him towards the
> house) Stop shoving me. You’ll knock me down. I’m warning you, stop
> it!

I could find a note on this usage of *perii!* from [Oxford commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=z4vIAiQPfb8C&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=%22often%20a%20mere%20exclamation%22&source=bl&ots=QbcF1UOwQi&sig=ACfU3U1uKKASY4UMgC2NGfwiQCFetBJIgA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinuLe9i-jyAhU5hv0HHfPgALQQ6AF6BAgKEAM#v=onepage&q=%22often%20a%20mere%20exclamation%22&f=false) from Terence:

> **perii:** here [other line] literally 'I'm ruined', though often a mere exclamation , 'damn it!', 'hell!' [as in the quoted line]